# How to solve the functional equation $f(x^n+y^n)=f(x^n)+f(y^n)$ for any positive integar $n$?

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

I got some problems when solving the functional equation $f(x+y^n)=f(x)+[f(y)]^n, (x,y\in\mathbf{R}) $ for all positive integar $n$. I tried to solve it as following:

================================================

Let $y=0$, then $f(x)=f(x)+[f(0)]^n$ implies $f(0)=0$;

Let $x=0, y=1$, then $f(1)=[f(1)]^n$ implies $f(1)=0$ or $1$.

Let $x=0$, then $f(y^n)=[f(y)]^n$.

Then the equation can be re-written as

$f(x^n+y^n)=f(x^n)+f(y^n), x, y\in\mathbf{R}$. ------- [1]

According to the continuous solution of Cauchy equation, the solution of the funciton (1) is $f(x)=f(1)x=0$ or $x$.

================================================

However, I want to know about:

(1) Whether my solution above is correct?

(2) Maybe I shall discuss the parity of $n$, or not. And how to solve the equation $f(x^n+y^n)=f(x^n)+f(y^n)$ for a general positive integar $n$.

(3) If all solutions of equation [1] have been found, then does the equation $f(x+y^n)=f(x)+[f(y)]^n$ have other solution which is not the solution of [1]?

Comment: If the equation in the title holds for any $x,y$, the the exponent $n$ is irrelevant and you can write $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, so that $f$ is linear, $f(x)=\lambda x$.

Comment: how about an even $n$ like $2$? $f(x^2+y^2)=f(x^2)+f(y^2)$ just describes the properties of $f$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Makes the function undefined for negative arguments.

Comment: @Antinous emm, in fact, I want to know how to solve both of them.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see. And are all solutions of $f(x+y^n)=f(x)+[f(y)]^n$ linear? Or can we find any other solution of $f(x+y^n)=f(x)+[f(y)]^n$ doesn't have the form $f(x)=f(1)x$?

Comment: Do you mean that the equation is valid for *a given* $n$, or for *all* $n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As Yves Daoust mentions, any such $f$ will be additive. Over $\mathbb{R}$, without some condition $f(x)=cx$ is one solution but not the only one - there are infinitely many pathological solutions. For more information, see this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) which gives some insight as to why nonlinear additive functions exist.